# PDO statement breaking loop

Tags: php, sql

I am setting up an ecommerce site and have set up a cron job to run a php script every so often to communicate with my payment gateway and update my database when the payment has gone through.

The following code with the line commented out gives me ALL of the transaction ID's with their status as expected. It also goes into the `if($status == 'settled')` statement so I can see the word test after each one.

```
$params = ['processing payment'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE status=?";
$stmt = DB::run($sql,$params);
$orderCount = $stmt->rowCount();
if ($orderCount > 0) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $id = $row["id"];
        $transaction_id = $row["transaction_id"];
        
        $transaction = Braintree_Transaction::find($transaction_id);
        $status = $transaction->status;
        
        echo $transaction_id.' - '.$status.'<br />';
        
        if($status == 'settled'){
            echo 'test<br />';
            $params = ['payment settled',$id];
            $sql = "UPDATE orders SET status=?, date_last_status_change=now() WHERE id=?";
            // $stmt = DB::run($sql,$params);
        }
    }
}
```

However when I un-comment that line it will only echo the first id and test and only update the first entry in the database it just seems to stop the loop and I can't figure out why. The line in question is correct because this is how I do all my queries and it actually does update the first entry.

Comment: Because you override `$stmt` inside the loop.

Comment: @JonStirling Cheers thanks so much, I completely missed that. Shouldn't be asking questions at the end of the day when I need coffee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, rename nested queries:

```
$params = [];
$sql = "";
$stmt = DB::run($sql,$params);
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $params1 = [];
    $sql1 = "";
    $stmt1 = DB::run($sql1,$params1);
}
```